# Inventory System tables

Tags: php, vb.net, cakephp, c#-4.0, cakephp-3.0

Can anybody  help me on designing tables in an INVENTORY system, I want to build an inventory system. Please help me also on how tables related to each other by joining using ID'S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design database according to your needs. though you can get help from here.

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/customers_and_inventory_mgt/index.htm

if you want more just check [here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/)